# Динамическое создание фреймов в WPF проекте

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Объект Page описанный языком XAML.

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Title="Page1">
<Canvas>
    <Button Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="200" Click="Button_Click">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedRotateTransform" Angle="0" />
        </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>

                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="60">
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRotateTransform"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                From="-5"
                                To="355"
                                Duration="0:0:0:2"
                                DecelerationRatio="1"
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>

                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
        <Button.Content>
            <TextBlock FontSize="50">
                Click me!!!
            </TextBlock>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation animation = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation();
                animation.From = (sender as Button).ActualHeight;
                animation.To = (sender as Button).ActualHeight + 50;
                animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

                (sender as Button).BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, animation);
            }
        ]]>
    </x:Code>
</Canvas>
```

Я могу воспользоваться XamlWriter и XamlReader для сериализации объекта. Но вся анимация и связанный код C# при компиляции оказываются в отдельном файле Page1.g.cs, хотя возможно это не единственный файл.
Есть ли способ записать данный фрейм со всеми обработчиками событий и анимацией в файл. А затем во время работы приложения считать ранее записанный файл(ы) и запустить их?

Comment: Какая конечная цель? Что этим всем вы пытаетесь осуществить?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Возможно, преподаватель с помощью этого приложения будет загружать работы студентов, и сразу же просматривать их. Где клиент студентов будет упаковывать их Page, а клиент преподавателя распаковывать.

Comment: А почему бы тогда не загружать всё приложение, с исходниками и исполнимым файлом?

Comment: (Это настолько же небезопасно, по идее.)

Comment: @VladD Я просто учусь. И я очень хочу реализовать эту задумку. Если вы хоть примерно знаете как её реализовать, пожалуйста помогите =)

Comment: @лалалалала: Ну, почему бы не копировать целый исполнимый файл?

Comment: почему бы просто не запустить анимацию из xaml?

Comment: Если чисто теоретически, то способ есть - посмотрите как работает [FsXAML](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml)